# How do I write a stack driver log query that samples 5% of all logs returned?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I keep reading that I can write a log query to sample a percentage of logs but I have found zero examples.

[https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/preventing-log-waste-with-stackdriver-logging\](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/preventing-log-waste-with-stackdriver-logging%5C)
`You can also choose to sample certain messages so that only a percentage of the messages appear in Stackdriver Logs Viewer`

How do I get 10% of all GCE load balancer logs with a log query? I know I can configure this on the backend, but I don't want that. I want to get 100% of logs in stackdriver and create a pub/sub log sink with a log query that only captures 10% of them and sends those sampled logs somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you'll want to create a Pub/Sub sink for Log Router. See [Configure and manage sinks](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2?hl=en#supported-destinations)

Using Google's Log querying, you can use [sample](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logging-query-language#sample) to filter (inclusion) logs.

Comment: I'm a little confused about how `sample()` works. Looks like it requires you specify a FIELD? I suppose I could specify a field I know will always be there, but I want to get 10% of all logs filtered via the query. Can you use `sample()` and only specify a sample number with a FIELD and just have it sample all logs the query is filtering? Want to make sure I'm understanding how it works.

Comment: The documentation in the link suggests using a (string|numeric) field that's always present and suggests `insertId`. Then for `FRACTION` you'll want `0.1` (10%).